# "Slicing" single object in PHP5

Tags: php

I'm bashing my head for an hour now. It seems that my `if` clause gets executed several times:

```
$req = $_GET['cc'];
foreach($prices->prices as $countryname => $country) {
  if ($country->name == $req)
    $a = (string) $country->currencyname;
  }
}
```

There is only a single object that matches my request, but `$a` is set to:

> nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull"ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS""ILS"

`null` for each *not matched* element and "ILS" for *matching element* and all elements after.

How do I make it match only *once*?

Comment: missed a bracket after if statement:
if ($country->name == $req) { <<<<

Comment: if the length of the matched string is fix like null, is 4 charachters or ils is 3 charachters, you can use substring and cutt it of.

Comment: Your foreach loop iterates on on array but a string, as I think. This looks like a column or a value in  array ($prices->prices ). Try to make your foreach too loop (foreach $prices-> as $countryname => $country) {} and then it may work.

Comment: Thanks to Alberto! It was indeed missing opening bracket, but due to circumstances, code did not produce any errors!

Answer (score 2):

User break to stop loop

```
if ($country->name == $req) {
    $a = (string) $country->currencyname;
    break;
}
```